# How to copy a 2D array into a 3rd dimension, N times?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'd like to copy a numpy 2D array into a third dimension. For example, given the 2D numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
# arr.shape = (2, 2)
```

convert it into a 3D matrix with N such copies in a new dimension. Acting on `arr` with `N=3`, the output should be:

```py
new_arr[:,:,0]
# array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])

new_arr[:,:,1]
# array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])

new_arr[:,:,2]
# array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])

# new_arr.shape = (2, 2, 3)
```

Comment: Simply new_arr = np.array([a]*3)  where a = [[1,2],[1,2]] worked for me.

Comment: @JStrahl: if a is of shape (r,c), then `np.array([a]*3)` produces an array of shape (3,r,c), while I assume the OP wants (r,c,3).

Comment: @mins the OP wants (3, r, c) as can be seen by the new_arr.shape = (3,2,2). So this works.

Comment: As a question asking for how to copy and paste and use [[1, 2], [1, 2]] as an example, this is bad.  I hope I can cast downvote.

Comment: @anon01 Your edit to make the slices at `axis=0` has now invalidated most of the answers for your question (including mine and the accepted answer).  Before, your question's context was to stack the slices in the third dimension (`axis=2`). I now need to edit my question (probably delete it as my method only applies for `axis=2`) for this new behaviour. I want to confirm this is actually what you want before changing my answer.

Comment: @rayryeng can you provide a link to the edit

Comment: Revision 4. You've made the 3D matrix slice into the first dimension. https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32171917/4. I admit that I haven't been here in years as I've answered this in 2015. This edit that changes most of the answers is from 2019.

Comment: @rayryeng ah, the real issue is the question text doesn't match the example code. In [revision 3](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/32171917/3) (and prev) the output arr is already of shape `(3,2,2)`

Comment: @rayryeng at a glance, most top answers are valid for the question text rather than expected arr code. Thanks for the catch, I'll revise accordingly

Comment: @anon01 Thanks! Yes, I meant the code sample edit, not the actual question content itself. Thanks for being so quick!

Answer (score 266, accepted):

Probably the cleanest way is to use [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html):

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
print(a.shape)
# (2,  2)

# indexing with np.newaxis inserts a new 3rd dimension, which we then repeat the
# array along, (you can achieve the same effect by indexing with None, see below)
b = np.repeat(a[:, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=2)

print(b.shape)
# (2, 2, 3)

print(b[:, :, 0])
# [[1 2]
#  [1 2]]

print(b[:, :, 1])
# [[1 2]
#  [1 2]]

print(b[:, :, 2])
# [[1 2]
#  [1 2]]
```

---

Having said that, you can often avoid repeating your arrays altogether by using [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). For example, let's say I wanted to add a `(3,)` vector:

```
c = np.array([1, 2, 3])
```

to `a`. I could copy the contents of `a` 3 times in the third dimension, then copy the contents of `c` twice in both the first and second dimensions, so that both of my arrays were `(2, 2, 3)`, then compute their sum. However, it's much simpler and quicker to do this:

```
d = a[..., None] + c[None, None, :]
```

Here, `a[..., None]` has shape `(2, 2, 1)` and `c[None, None, :]` has shape `(1, 1, 3)`*. When I compute the sum, the result gets 'broadcast' out along the dimensions of size 1, giving me a result of shape `(2,  2,  3)`:

```
print(d.shape)
# (2,  2, 3)

print(d[..., 0])    # a + c[0]
# [[2 3]
#  [2 3]]

print(d[..., 1])    # a + c[1]
# [[3 4]
#  [3 4]]

print(d[..., 2])    # a + c[2]
# [[4 5]
#  [4 5]]
```

Broadcasting is a very powerful technique because it avoids the additional overhead involved in creating repeated copies of your input arrays in memory.

---

* Although I included them for clarity, the `None` indices into `c` aren't actually necessary - you could also do `a[..., None] + c`, i.e. broadcast a `(2, 2, 1)` array against a `(3,)` array. This is because if one of the arrays has fewer dimensions than the other then only the *trailing* dimensions of the two arrays need to be compatible. To give a more complicated example:

```
a = np.ones((6, 1, 4, 3, 1))  # 6 x 1 x 4 x 3 x 1
b = np.ones((5, 1, 3, 2))     #     5 x 1 x 3 x 2
result = a + b                # 6 x 5 x 4 x 3 x 2
```

Comment: To verify that this indeed gives the right result, you can also print out `b[:,:,0]`, `b[:,:,1]`, and `b[:,:,2]`. Each third dimension slice is a copy of the original 2D array. This isn't as obvious just looking at `print(b)`.

Comment: What is the difference between None and np.newaxis? When i tested it, it gave the same result.

Comment: @wedran They are exactly the same - `np.newaxis` is just an alias of `None`

Comment: You can do "b = np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, :, :], 3, axis=0)" to repeat 3 times and add to the first dimension.

Answer (score 48):

Another way is to use [`numpy.dstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html).  Supposing that you want to repeat the matrix `a` `num_repeats` times:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.dstack([a]*num_repeats)
```

The trick is to wrap the matrix `a` into a list of a single element, then using the `*` operator to duplicate the elements in this list `num_repeats` times.

For example, if:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
num_repeats = 5
```

This repeats the array of `[1 2; 1 2]` 5 times in the third dimension.  To verify (in IPython):

```
In [110]: import numpy as np

In [111]: num_repeats = 5

In [112]: a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])

In [113]: b = np.dstack([a]*num_repeats)

In [114]: b[:,:,0]
Out[114]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [115]: b[:,:,1]
Out[115]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [116]: b[:,:,2]
Out[116]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [117]: b[:,:,3]
Out[117]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [118]: b[:,:,4]
Out[118]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])

In [119]: b.shape
Out[119]: (2, 2, 5)
```

At the end we can see that the shape of the matrix is `2 x 2`, with 5 slices in the third dimension.

Comment: How does this compare to `reshape`? Faster? gives the same structure? Its definitely neater.

Comment: @AnderBiguri I've never benchmarked... I put this in here primarily for completeness. It'll be interesting to time and see the differences.

Comment: I just did img = np.dstack([arr] * 3) and worked fine! Thank you

Comment: Figured I could propose a viewed output for efficiency. Being an old post, people might have missed that. Added a solution on this Q&A.

Answer (score 36):

### Use a view and get free runtime! Extend generic `n-dim` arrays to `n+1-dim`

Introduced in [NumPy `1.10.0`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/release.html#new-function-np-broadcast-to-for-invoking-array-broadcasting), we can leverage [`numpy.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) to simply generate a `3D` view into the `2D` input array. The benefit would be no extra memory overhead and virtually free runtime. This would be essential in cases where the arrays are big and we are okay to work with views. Also, this would work with generic `n-dim` cases.

I would use the word `stack` in place of `copy`, as readers might confuse it with the copying of arrays that creates memory copies.

**Stack along first axis**

If we want to stack input `arr` along the first axis, the solution with `np.broadcast_to` to create `3D` view would be -

```
np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape) # N = 3 here
```

**Stack along third/last axis**

To stack input `arr` along the third axis, the solution to create `3D` view would be -

```
np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None],arr.shape+(3,))
```

If we actually need a memory copy, we can always append `.copy()` there. Hence, the solutions would be -

```
np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape).copy()
np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None],arr.shape+(3,)).copy()
```

Here's how the stacking works for the two cases, shown with their shape information for a sample case -

```
# Create a sample input array of shape (4,5)
In [55]: arr = np.random.rand(4,5)

# Stack along first axis
In [56]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape).shape
Out[56]: (3, 4, 5)

# Stack along third axis
In [57]: np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None],arr.shape+(3,)).shape
Out[57]: (4, 5, 3)
```

Same solution(s) would work to extend a `n-dim` input to `n+1-dim` view output along the first and last axes. Let's explore some higher dim cases -

**3D input case :**

```
In [58]: arr = np.random.rand(4,5,6)

# Stack along first axis
In [59]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape).shape
Out[59]: (3, 4, 5, 6)

# Stack along last axis
In [60]: np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None],arr.shape+(3,)).shape
Out[60]: (4, 5, 6, 3)
```

**4D input case :**

```
In [61]: arr = np.random.rand(4,5,6,7)

# Stack along first axis
In [62]: np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape).shape
Out[62]: (3, 4, 5, 6, 7)

# Stack along last axis
In [63]: np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None],arr.shape+(3,)).shape
Out[63]: (4, 5, 6, 7, 3)
```

and so on.

#### Timings

Let's use a large sample `2D` case and get the timings and verify output being a `view`.

```
# Sample input array
In [19]: arr = np.random.rand(1000,1000)
```

Let's prove that the proposed solution is a view indeed. We will use stacking along first axis (results would be very similar for stacking along the third axis) -

```
In [22]: np.shares_memory(arr, np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape))
Out[22]: True
```

Let's get the timings to show that it's virtually free -

```
In [20]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.56 µs per loop

In [21]: %timeit np.broadcast_to(arr,(3000,)+arr.shape)
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.51 µs per loop
```

Being a view, increasing `N` from `3` to `3000` changed nothing on timings and both are negligible on timing units. Hence, efficient both on memory and performance!

Comment: This is a great option. However, I feel that the time needed to operate on the created views may be important. For instance, having `a = np.zeros((1000,1000))`, the timings for a simple multiplication are: with **np.repeat** --> `%timeit np.repeat(a[:,:,None], 3, axis=-1)*2.0` gives `26.4 ms ± 456 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`. With **np.broadcast_to** --> `%timeit np.broadcast_to(a[:,:,None], a.shape+(3,))*2.0` gives `29.8 ms ± 394 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)`

Answer (score 13):

This can now also be achived using [np.tile](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html) as follows:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,2],[1,2]])
b = np.tile(a,(3, 1,1))

b.shape
(3,2,2)

b
array([[[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]],

       [[1, 2],
        [1, 2]]])
```

Answer (score 4):

```
A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
B=np.asarray([A]*N)
```

Edit @Mr.F, to preserve dimension order:

```
B=B.T
```

Comment: This results in an N x 2 x 2 array for me, e.g. `B.shape` prints `(N, 2, 2)` for whatever value of `N`.  If you transpose `B` with `B.T` then it matches the expected output.

Comment: @Mr.F - You're correct.  This will broadcast along the first dimension, and so doing `B[0], B[1],...` will give you the right slice, which I'll argue and say that's more easier to type rather than using `B[:,:,0], B[:,:,1]`, etc.

Comment: It may be easier to type, but for example if you are doing this with image data it would largely be incorrect, since almost all algorithms will expect the conventions of linear algebra to be used for the 2D slices of pixel channels. It's hard to imagine an applications where you start with a 2D array, treating rows and columns with a certain convention, and then you want multiple copies of that same thing extending into a new axis, but suddenly you want the first axis to change meaning to be the new axis...

Comment: @Mr.F - Oh certainly.  I can't guess on what applications you'll want to use the 3D matrix in the future.  That being said, it all depends on the application.  FWIW, I prefer the `B[:,:,i]` as well as that is what I'm accustomed to.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a broadcasting example that does exactly what was requested.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 2]])
a=a[:,:,None]
b=np.array([1]*5)[None,None,:]
```

Then `b*a` is the desired result and `(b*a)[:,:,0]` produces `array([[1, 2],[1, 2]])`, which is the original `a`, as does `(b*a)[:,:,1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing the solutions above:

```
a = np.arange(9).reshape(3,-1)
b = np.repeat(a[:, :, np.newaxis], 5, axis=2)
c = np.dstack([a]*5)
d = np.tile(a, [5,1,1])
e = np.array([a]*5)
f = np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, :, :], 5, axis=0) # np.repeat again
print('b='+ str(b.shape), b[:,:,-1].tolist())
print('c='+ str(c.shape),c[:,:,-1].tolist())
print('d='+ str(d.shape),d[-1,:,:].tolist())
print('e='+ str(e.shape),e[-1,:,:].tolist())
print('f='+ str(f.shape),f[-1,:,:].tolist())

b=(3, 3, 5) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
c=(3, 3, 5) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
d=(5, 3, 3) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
e=(5, 3, 3) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
f=(5, 3, 3) [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8]]
```

Good luck