# Create 3D array from a 2D array by replicating/repeating along the first axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Suppose I have a `n × m` array, i.e.:

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

And I what to generate a 3D array `k × n × m`, where all the arrays in the new axis are equal, i.e.: the same array but now `3 × 3 × 3`.

```
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

      [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

      [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

How can I get it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Introduce a new axis at the start with [`None/np.newaxis`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) and replicate along it with [`np.repeat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html). This should work for extending any `n` dim array to `n+1` dim array. The implementation would be -

```
np.repeat(arr[None,...],k,axis=0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [143]: arr
Out[143]: 
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])

In [144]: np.repeat(arr[None,...],3,axis=0)
Out[144]: 
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

**`View-output` for memory-efficiency**

We can also generate a `3D` view and achieve virtually free runtime with [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html). More info - [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54269982/). Hence, simply do -

```
np.broadcast_to(arr,(3,)+arr.shape) # repeat 3 times
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

You can use a list comprehension to generate the duplicate array:

```
b = [a for x in range(3)]
```

Then (for numpy):

```
c = array(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use default broadcasting to replicate your array:

```
a = np.arange(1, 10).reshape(3,3)
n = 3
b = np.ones((n, 3, 3)) * a
```

Which results in the array you wanted:

```
array([[[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]],

       [[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
        [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
        [ 7.,  8.,  9.]]])
```

This won't work by default if you want to replicate it along another axis. In that case you would need to be explicit with the dimensions to ensure correct broadcasting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is exactly the answer of [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38607674/9868445), but the syntax might be a bit easier to understand for a beginner(at least in my case, it is):

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
a[np.newaxis,:,:].repeat(3,axis=0)
```

results in:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]],

       [[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6]]])
```

I learned about **np.newaxis** here: [What is numpy.newaxis and when to use it.](https://medium.com/@ian.dzindo01/what-is-numpy-newaxis-and-when-to-use-it-8cb61c7ed6ae)

And about **numpy.repeat** here: [numpy.repeat](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html)

---

Here's an example usage I needed this for:

```
k = np.array([[[111,121,131,141,151],[211,221,231,241,251]],\
              [[112,122,132,142,152],[212,222,232,242,252]],\
              [[113,123,133,143,153],[213,223,233,243,253]]])

filter = np.array([[True,True,True,True,False], 
                   [True,False,False,True,False]])
k[filter[None,...].repeat(3,axis=0)] = 0
print(k)
```

results in:

```
[[[  0   0   0   0 151]
  [  0 221 231   0 251]]

 [[  0   0   0   0 152]
  [  0 222 232   0 252]]

 [[  0   0   0   0 153]
  [  0 223 233   0 253]]]
```