# how to convert 64x64 images to 64x64x64 volumes by creating a fake z axis?

Tags: python, matrix, 3d, 2d, slice

I am trying to create fake z-axis by copying MxN values. For example,

let's assume we have a 4x4 matrix

```
0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 0
0 3 4 0
0 0 0 0
```

after converting the array 4x4x4, the next slice should be exactly the same.

```
0 0 0 0 
0 1 2 0
0 3 4 0
0 0 0 0
```

If we make it 4x4x4 and if we look from the right side we should see the side of volume like this:

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

and the next slice of the rotated volume should be:

```
0 0 0 0
2 2 2 2
4 4 4 4
0 0 0 0
```

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description. However, we need you to [ask a question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We can't be sure what you want from us. Please [edit] your post to include a valid question and [mcve] of what you tried so we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know [what is on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create 3D array from a 2D array by replicating/repeating along the first axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38607546/create-3d-array-from-a-2d-array-by-replicating-repeating-along-the-first-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operation you want to achieve is called broadcasting. 
You can find more information in keras documentation or in numpy documentation. 
[Here for example](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

Using numpy library (it is arguably more common than keras or tensorflow). You can for example write it like this.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0.0,1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [0.0, 10.0, 20.0, 30.0], [432, 342, 342, 12]])
b = np.zeros(a.shape[0])
c = a[:, :, np.newaxis] + b
print(c)
```

Which provides the following outcome.

```
 array([[[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [  1.,   1.,   1.,   1.],
    [  2.,   2.,   2.,   2.],
    [  3.,   3.,   3.,   3.]],

   [[  4.,   4.,   4.,   4.],
    [  5.,   5.,   5.,   5.],
    [  6.,   6.,   6.,   6.],
    [  7.,   7.,   7.,   7.]],

   [[  0.,   0.,   0.,   0.],
    [ 10.,  10.,  10.,  10.],
    [ 20.,  20.,  20.,  20.],
    [ 30.,  30.,  30.,  30.]],

   [[432., 432., 432., 432.],
    [342., 342., 342., 342.],
    [342., 342., 342., 342.],
    [ 12.,  12.,  12.,  12.]]])
```

As a global remark, keep in mind, that "volume" here is a mathematical concept. In the way it is printed, first, second and third dimensions are commutable.

Therefore, those results are mathematically correct as well:

```
d = c.transpose()
print(d)

[[[  0.   4.   0. 432.]
  [  1.   5.  10. 342.]
  [  2.   6.  20. 342.]
  [  3.   7.  30.  12.]]

 [[  0.   4.   0. 432.]
  [  1.   5.  10. 342.]
  [  2.   6.  20. 342.]
  [  3.   7.  30.  12.]]

 [[  0.   4.   0. 432.]
  [  1.   5.  10. 342.]
  [  2.   6.  20. 342.]
  [  3.   7.  30.  12.]]

 [[  0.   4.   0. 432.]
  [  1.   5.  10. 342.]
  [  2.   6.  20. 342.]
  [  3.   7.  30.  12.]]]
```

and

```
e = d.transpose()
print(e)

[[[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [  1.   1.   1.   1.]
  [  2.   2.   2.   2.]
  [  3.   3.   3.   3.]]

 [[  4.   4.   4.   4.]
  [  5.   5.   5.   5.]
  [  6.   6.   6.   6.]
  [  7.   7.   7.   7.]]

 [[  0.   0.   0.   0.]
  [ 10.  10.  10.  10.]
  [ 20.  20.  20.  20.]
  [ 30.  30.  30.  30.]]

 [[432. 432. 432. 432.]
  [342. 342. 342. 342.]
  [342. 342. 342. 342.]
  [ 12.  12.  12.  12.]]]
```

It's up to you to choose which one is more user-friendly to you.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use pure python it can be as simple as multiplied list.

```
a = [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,2,0],[0,3,4,0],[0,0,0,0]]
result = [a] * 4
```

Now result is you 3-dimensional matrix.

Comment: This is way more elegant to use pure-python only. I would recommend this solution rather that the one I wrote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the numpy library:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
            [0, 1, 2, 0],
            [0, 3, 4, 0],
            [0, 0, 0, 0]])
a3d = np.dstack([a, a, a])
```

dstack() is similar to hstack() and vstack() (I memorized h for Horizontal, v for Vertical and d possibly for Depth).