# Numpy array of integers into numpy array of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to convert numpy array into numpy array of arrays.

I have an array: `a = [[0,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,255,255],[255,255,255]]`

and I would like to have: `b = [[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[255,255,255],[0,0,0]],[[0,0,0],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]],[[255,255,255],[255,255,255],[255,255,255]]]`

Is there any easy way to do it?

I have tried with `np.where(a == 0, [0,0,0],[255,255,255])` but I got the following error:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
```

Comment: what is the rule to replace the values?

Comment: If you are simply replicating, this is relevant : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171917/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you tried will work with the following small modification:

```
a = np.array(a)
np.where(a[...,None]==0,[0,0,0],[255,255,255])
```

To make multidimensional indexing available we have to cast `a` to `array` first. `a[...,None]` adds a new dimension at the end of `a` to accomodate the triplets 0,0,0 and 255,255,255.

Comment: @makis I've added a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `broadcast_to` as

```py
b = np.broadcast_to(a, (3,4,3))
```

where `a` was shape `(3,4)`.  Then you need to swap the axes around

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,255,255],[255,255,255]])
b = np.broadcast_to(a, (3,4,3))
c = np.moveaxis(b, [0,1,2], [2,0,1])
c
```

giving

```
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
```

A more direct method broadcasting method suggested by @Divakar is

```
 b = np.broadcast(a[:,:,None], (4,3,3))
```

which produces the same output without axis swapping.

Comment: Good idea there. Shorter and faster with extending dims upfront and then broadcasting : `np.broadcast_to(a[:,:,None], (4,3,3))`.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [204]: a = np.array([[0,0,0],[0,255,0],[0,255,255],[255,255,255]])           
In [205]: a.shape                                                               
Out[205]: (4, 3)
```

Looks like you want to replicate each element 3 times, making a new trailing dimension.  We can do that using `repeat` (after adding the new trailing dimension):

```
In [207]: a.reshape(4,3,1).repeat(3,2)                                          
Out[207]: 
array([[[  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [  0,   0,   0]],

       [[  0,   0,   0],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]],

       [[255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255],
        [255, 255, 255]]])
In [208]: _.shape                                                               
Out[208]: (4, 3, 3)
```