# Creating a list repeated n times using an existing variable which is mutable

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, immutability

I have an numpy array initialized as  `A = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])` I want to create a list `C = [A, A, A, A]`. I can do `C = [[A] * 4]` but that would generate a mutable list, changing one element will change others. I also know we can overcome this problem in this way: `C = [np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]) for _ in range(3)]` but this makes the code lengthy. Using  `C = [A for _ in range(3)]` doesn't help. I have verified below:

```
>>> R = np.array([[2,3,0], [6,78,8],[1,2,3]])
>>> R
array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
>>> U = [R for _ in range(3)]
>>> U[1]
array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
>>> U[2]
array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])
>>> U[2][2,2]
3
>>> U[1][2,2]
3
>>> U[1][2,2] = 0
>>> U[2][2,2]
0
>>> type(U)
<class 'list'>
```

What should I do to create the list, with each of the contents independent(i.e immutable)?

Comment: See if this solves it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171917/?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [copy 2D array into 3rd dimension, N times (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171917/copy-2d-array-into-3rd-dimension-n-times-python) cc. @Divakar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `.copy()`:

```py
import numpy as np


R = np.array([[2,3,0], [6,78,8],[1,2,3]])
U = [R.copy() for _ in range(3)]

U[1][2,2] = 0

print(U)
```

Gives:

```
[array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3]]),
 array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  0]]),
 array([[ 2,  3,  0],
       [ 6, 78,  8],
       [ 1,  2,  3]])]
```